# ButterKnife Fragment RecyclerView NPE

Tags: android, recyclerview, butterknife

Есть фрагмент

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private Realm mRealm;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Realm.init(getContext());
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(mRealm.where(MyBook.class).findAll()));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRealm.close();
}
}
```

Вот здесь mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); выбрасывается NPE(mRecyclerView == null), не понимаю, почему. Есть другие проекты там все работает, clean, rebuild пробовал.

код layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` в `onViewCreated` перенести

Comment: id у ресайклера точно тот?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тоже об этом подумал но чекнул на оф сайте баттеркнайфа, там биндинг именно в `onCreateView`

Comment: Перенос ButterKnife.bind(this, view); в onViewCreated не помогло. Id у recyclerview тот, по ctrl переходит куда надо

Comment: Хм попробуйте ребилднуть

Comment: ребилд не помогает

Comment: А `R.layout.fragment_list` по ctrl тоже переходит куда надо?

Comment: да, R.layout.fragment_list по ctrl тоже переходит куда надо

Comment: если делать через view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);, то все работает

Comment: `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'` - эта строка есть в зависимостях?

Comment: Добавил строку, все заработало, спасибо, только не пойму, почему. Есть второй фрагмент с edittext, там все нормально и без этой строки было

Comment: Там наверное имя поля совпадает с `id` и `ButterKnife` справляется без аннотаций